How do I get Cypress to wait for timeouts inside of a resolved task promise?
I have a Cypress test something like this:
it('redirects from ID to slug', () => {
  cy.setupEnvironment(params).then((environment) => {
    cy.visit(`/?id=${environment.id}`);

    cy.location("pathname", { timeout: 10_000 }).should(
      "eq",
      `/${environment.slug}`
    );
  });
});

setupEnvironment is a custom command that wraps a cy.task call that sets up DB etc.
// the task
async function setupEnvironmentTask(params) {
  await setUpDb();
  const { id, slug } = await setUpEntity(params);
  return { id, slug };
}

// that's then wrapped in a command
function setupEnvironment(params) {
  return cy.task("setupEnvironmentTask", params);
}

Cypress.Commands.add("setupEnvironment", setupEnvironment);

The problem is that the assertion on cy.location runs and fails immediately without respecting the timeout.
I can see the test data being spun up, and the initial visit call starts to load the page, but the test then fails straight away.
My best guess it that, because this is chained to the task, then that breaks out of Cypress's understanding of awaiting promises inside of callbacks.
Is there a way to get Cypress to finish with the task and return the data that can be used for assertions? Alias it into a var or such maybe?

Where is the task? I presume you mean a Cypress task cy.task('something')?

Or are you referring to the custom command when you say task?

Sorry - tried to keep the code short but made it more confusing. Updated now.

Here's a simple reproduction that may help you debug.
I set up a simple server to perform redirect on receiving a particular id:
server.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 7000;

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  if (req.query.id === '123') {
    setTimeout(() => {
      res.redirect('/user')
    }, 1000)                     // delay here for page compose etc
  } 
});
 
app.get('/user', function (req, res) {
  res.send("Redirected to User Page");
});
 
app.listen(PORT, function (err) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  console.log("Server listening on PORT", PORT);
});

I filled in the gaps on your sample test and ran it
test
function setupDb() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve()
    }, 1000)           // delay here to simulate stuff happening
    
  })
}
function setUpEntity(params) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({id: '123', slug: 'user'})
    }, 1000)                            // delay again - total setup 2 seconds
    
  })
}
async function setupEnvironment(params) {
  await setupDb();
  const { id, slug } = await setUpEntity(params);
  return { id, slug };
}
Cypress.Commands.add("setupEnvironment", setupEnvironment);

it('redirects from ID to slug', {baseUrl: 'http://localhost:7000'}, () => {
  const params = []
  cy.setupEnvironment(params).then((environment) => {
    cy.visit(`/?id=${environment.id}`)

    cy.location("pathname", { timeout: 3_000 })  // > server response time
      .should('eq', `/${environment.slug}`)
  })
})

The Cypress test passed

